# Error with DocumentListener

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextField that I want to be limited to fifteen characters. The problem is that when I type over 15 characters, it errors. How can i fix this? Do I have to use some other object?

The error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

```
 final int maxNicknameLength = 15;
 final JTextField nickname = new JTextField(1); //Max length: 15
 DocumentListener docListen = new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           lengthCheck(e, nickname, maxNicknameLength);
      }

      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           lengthCheck(e, nickname, maxNicknameLength);
      }

      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           lengthCheck(e, nickname, maxNicknameLength);
      }
      public void lengthCheck (DocumentEvent e, JTextField txt, int max) {
           if (txt.getText().length() > max)
                txt.setText(txt.getText().substring(0, max));
      }    
 };
 nickname.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListen);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a DocumentFilter, not a DocumentListener. By the time the listener fires the Document has already been updated. A filter will prevent the document from being updated.

See: [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a working example that does what your want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void lengthCheck(final DocumentEvent e, final JTextField txt, 
        final int max) {
    if (txt.getText().length() > max) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txt.setText(txt.getText().substring(0, max));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, the solution answers the question. However, this is not the best solution for the requirement. Use a DocumentFilter for a better solution.

Comment: Although it works, if DocumentFilter is what I'm supposed to use, I'll use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners):

> You may want to change the document's
>   text within a document listener.
>   However, you should never modify the
>   contents of a text component from
>   within a document listener. If you do,
>   the program will likely deadlock.
>   Instead, you can use a formatted text
>   field or provide a document filter.

There is a synchronization lock on the underlying `Document` and this lock is taken by the listener when inside your `lengthCheck` method.  Calling `setText` on the `JTextField` also tries to grab the lock on the `Document`, which is not possible.